# unable to load files in /var/www on localhost

Tags: apache2, localhost, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I don't know why, but until recently, I could load files located in /var/www/ by typing the folder name in my browser, and I could load files located in /var/www/html by using localhost/<>

Now, the files in /var/www/html still load, but the ones in /var/www don't and give the error "this page isn't working <> didn't send any data.

I've tried restarting apache2 and also restarting WSL2 from powershell as well as restarting my machine.

Everything seems to be in order with the conf files for the sites as well as apache2.conf -- in fact the settings are exactly the same as the settings on my VPS server, which loads my sites fine.

I'd welcome any suggestions as to what else to try.

Comment: might as well post an update: I just did apt-update and installed net-tools on WSL2 Debian distro - only because I was trying to check the network setup - and now the sites in /var/www/ are working!  Doesn't really explain things, but at least it's working.

Comment: ... spoke too soon, back to how it was after re-start